# MySQL group as for existing column

Tags: mysql

I have a query like so:

```
SELECT COUNT(t.ID), 
    CASE WHEN t.Area = "Downtownn" 
    THEN "Downtown" 
    ELSE t.Area END as "Area" 
FROM MyTable t 
GROUP BY Area
```

Now this kinda works, if I change the name of the AS and reference that in the group by everything works as expected, however because Area is an existing column the Group by gets me the wrong results, is there away override this column?

Comment: Side note: Don't get used to use double quotes for string or date literals. Yes, sadly MySQL accepts that, but in SQL double quotes are usually for identifiers, such as column names. Should you ever use another DBMS (or future MySQL versions become more sane about this) you'll likely get an "invalid object name" error. Always use single quotes for string or date literals.

Comment: Just repeat the `CASE` expression in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Change the alias to something else although the correct solution is to copy paste the case expr in group by.

Comment: Or fix the misspellings in your data! :-)

Comment: Why don't you update the table to the correct values and avoid such problems?

Comment: Because some values are in french, others in english

Comment: `UPDATE MyTable SET Area = 'Downtown' WHERE Area = 'Downtownn'` is the best solution for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the query in a subquery, then do the grouping in the main query.

```
SELECT Count, Area
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(t.ID) AS Count, 
        CASE WHEN t.Area = 'Downtownn'
        THEN 'Downtown'
        ELSE t.Area END as "Area" 
    FROM MyTable t
) AS x
GROUP BY Area
```

Or you can do the grouping in the subquery by giving it a different alias, then rename it in the main query.

```
SELECT c AS Count, a AS Area
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(t.ID) AS c, 
        CASE WHEN t.Area = 'Downtownn'
        THEN 'Downtown'
        ELSE t.Area END as a
    FROM MyTable t
    GROUP BY a
) AS x
```

Note that using aliases in `GROUP BY` is a MySQL extension in the first place, so the first solution above is the way you'd do it in standard SQL (or repeat the `CASE` expression in `GROUP BY`).